# Why am I getting design-time error?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Winforms project with a FormMain.cs. I can build the project without error and it functions as a start up project.

However, when I click on FormMain.cs to access the design view, I see the following design-time error list:

> Could not find type
>   'UserControlsTabbed.UserControlTabPanel'.
>   Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is
>   referenced. If this type is a part of your development project, make
>   sure that the project has been successfully built using settings for
>   your current platform or Any CPU.

and

> The variable 'userControlTabPanel1' is either undeclared or was
>   never assigned.

I certainly recall using the design view of FormMain.cs. I recall placing userControlTabPanel1 in a tableLayoutPanel cell within FormMain.cs. I did not have any design-view errors at that time. That was perhaps 100-150 version ago in my code repository. I have not had any need to access the design view of FormMain.cs until now.

The second error message is especially confusing. Opening FormMain.Designer.cs I see that the auto-generated code contains both the declaration and assignment.

I am confused as to why the winforms application executes without issue but the design-view has errors. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: That probably should have been an edit to your question instead of a comment.

Comment: Most probably you are referencing wrong (.Net) version of assembly.

Comment: Second part is result of first one. It will be fixed if you fix first one

Comment: All projects in solution are targeting framework 4.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues causing this problem.

1. Project Platform target must be set to x86.
2. `TableLayoutPanel` do not support visual inheritance. Instead, use containers that support visual inheritance such as `GroupBox`, `Panel`, `SplitContainer`, or `TabControl`.
3. Inheriting usercontrols that do not conform to 1. and 2. of this list causes errors in the design-view.

By implementing the above 3 observations in my solution I was able to successfully remove the Design-time errors.